# Open link in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

I tried various ways to open the link in new window in .js file imported in a .ftl file, but it's not working out.

Below is the code in .js

```js
$(".termsAndCondition").on("click", function() {
  var web_url = localStorage.getItem("webUrl");
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = `${web_url}TermsAndConditions`.prop(
      "target",
      "_blank"
    );
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. localStorage return a string  - what string would that be that resolves the string `${web_url}TermsAndConditions` into an object with prop?
2. window.location.href opens URL in same window, you can use window.open but that may trigger popup blockers
3. Why timeout?

Just use a link with `target="_blank"`

```
<a href="termsandconditions.html" target="_blank">Terms and conditions</a>
```

This is not valid JS

```
window.location.href = `${web_url}TermsAndConditions`.prop(
  "target",
  "_blank"
);
```

Comment: it's a next.js project with .flt used for keycloak just for authentication purpose, that is why cannot use <a href directly.

Comment: So what is the web_url and what is the HTML you click?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `window.open()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). You could call something like

```js
window.open('termsandconditions.html');
```

in your javascript. This method is a also a vanilla JS way for opening a window in a new tab. The target can be set as follows:

```js
window.open('URL','TARGET');
```

where TARGET can be left blank (as with first example) to open with new window, set to _self to open in the same window, etc.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Sounds good, @dhavalpawale! Let me know if it works for you. If not, tell me and I will investigate the source of the problem.

Comment: window.open will trigger a popup blocker

Comment: @mplungjan, you are correct, but this behavior is only seen in early versions of IE, or if a window.open is called onload. I, in fact, use window.open extensively on my personal website, and have never experienced, nor have had issues from anyone else with, a popup blocker being used to deny this. The website https://www.yaplex.com/blog/avoid-browser-pop-up-blockers explains that any window.open as a result of "direct user action" (ie OP button click)  will not be blocked.

Comment: @Finn_Lancaster except the open is NOT on a direct action but deferred using setTimeout

Comment: It occurs on button click: $(".termsAndCondition").on("click", function()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open()` method for this as below,

```
$(".termsAndCondition").on("click", function() {
  var web_url = localStorage.getItem("webUrl");
  window.open(`${web_url}TermsAndConditions`, "_blank");
});
```

Or a self removing anchor tag as below,

```
$(".termsAndCondition").on("click", function() {
  var web_url = localStorage.getItem("webUrl");
  var a = $("<a>").appendTo(document.body).attr({
    href: `${web_url}TermsAndConditions`,
    target: "_blank"
  });
  a.get(0).click();
  a.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now resolved with target="_blank" and oh my god, for whole afternoon I was working in a wrong file. I took it over from another dev in between and we are actually maintaining 2 projects with 2 dev environments, and I mistook 1 for another. Thanks @mplungjan, @Finn_Lancaster, @Wazeed.